# MySQL hangs a user when running a query

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I give you some technical details before going forward to the issue:

- **MySQL Version**: 5.3.1
- **Engine**: Innodb
- Server running under Centos

I'm experiencing some troubles in the user connections when running certain queries. For this example to show you my problem I will make a query **slow enough to provoke this** scenario to happen.

Lets say I have my user "**testuser1**" and I use it to run a **2 minutes long** query (long in purpose). While this query is running I try to run another query with the same user (and different tables) but it doesn't actually run until the first query finish (Kind of **sequential**).

First thing I thought is... well, maybe those **tables are locked?** (even tho I cannot even connect to the database at all).

So I tried to use a new user "**testuser2**" while this query was running. In this case I didn't have any problem at all on connecting to the database and running queries.

After this I thought the user might be blocked, so I tried to connect 
 my "**testuser1**" to a different database with no issue.

The next thing I tried was to use "**testuser1**" on a different IP while the first one was running. However I didn't experience any issue on running my queries.

Does anyone know why I cannot run two queries at a time on the same IP and how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, table locks can be an issue.

Comment: @Shadow Yep, that's the first thing I thought but if you read all I've tried after that you will see how that's not the case...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us more. Are the two queries you're attempting to run on behalf of `testuser1` using different database connections? (They won't work at the same time on the same connection of course.) What are you doing to make your query slow? Who is your hosting provider. Do they impose any limits on simultaneous connections?  By the way, version 5.3.1 is quite old, and the MySQL team has improved many things since then.